# Strange text appended to output of ls command

Tags: linux, bash

This is completely my fault.  I did something stupid and I don't know how to fix it. I installed gpm, a console mouse server and was testing it.  This is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install gpm
man gpm
selected some random text from man page with mouse
pasted this random text with mouse
```

Now whenever I type the ls command (in this case directory is empty) this is what happens:

```
doug@debian:~$ ls
e the right butt on each line will be removed from the ole holding the selection will clear the
```

My bash history file doesn't show what command I've typed to change the behavior of ls.  It's still aliased correctly as ls='ls --color=auto'

What could I have done?  I feel stupid :(

Comment: But maybe there is a file with that name in there.  Show us `ls -la .`

Comment: @JuliePelletier You are correct.  I removed two files and now the ls command is back to _normal_  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That listing shows what is actually present in that directory.

The spaces in the file name(s) makes it impossible to distinguish them clearly.  Using a long listing (`ls -l`) allows to get a better picture of the situation.